# CORS policy Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, sockets, cors

I am creating a react application with node as backend But shows this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?id=21af3bd7-faea-4300-8e2a-6866fe8274b1&EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NNPqjV0' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is my full server side code

```
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  })
);
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  const id = socket.handshake.query.id;
  socket.join(id);

  socket.on("send-message", ({ recipients, text }) => {
    recipients.forEach((recipient) => {
      const newRecipients = recipients.filter((r) => r !== recipient);
      newRecipients.push(id);
      socket.broadcast.to(recipient).emit("receive-message", {
        recipients: newRecipients,
        sender: id,
        text,
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Use app.use(cors()); so it wil let acces the apis from different server, You don't need the give the particluar address

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you used the correct port, if you have I don't really know why it shouldn't work if you have used the correct port but you could try one of those options:

**To add more then one port**

```js
    app.use(cors({
        origin: [
            'http://localhost:someport',
            'https://localhost:port',
        ],
    }));
```

**OR**

```js
    app.use(cors());
```

To allow all origins.

Answer (score 0):

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```